# C++ - Nested for loop optimizations

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, vector, parallel-processing

**Problem**

I have some code that I need to optimize for work. Given two datasets, I need to compare every element in one dataset with every element in another. The elements in the datasets are string vectors. that look like this: `{"AB", "BB", "AB", "AA", "AB", ...}`, where there are 3 possible values: `AB`, `BB`, and `AA`. So for example, one dataset would be something like:

```
AB AA BB BB AA AB
AB AA AA AA BB AB
AA AA AB BB BB BB
```

while the other dataset might be

```
BB AB AB AA AB AB
AA AA BB BB BB BB
```

Note: The vector length will be the same within and between datasets. In this case, it's length `6`.

So the first data set contains three vectors, and the second dataset contains two for a total of 6 comparisons

This example contained 3 vs 2 vectors. My real problem will have something like 1.3M vs 6,000

**Reproducible Example**

The following code will create the vectors to the datasets to the desired sizes similar to how they'll show up in my real code. The first part of the main function simply generates the datasets. This part doesn't need to be optimized because these will be read in from a file. I'm generating them here for the sake of this question. The part that needs to be optimized is the nested for loop in the latter part of the main function

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Takes in a 2D string vector by reference, and fills it to the required size with AA, AB, or BB
void make_genotype_data(int numRows, int numCols, std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& geno) {
  std::string vals[3] = {"AA", "AB", "BB"};
  for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    std::vector<std::string> markers;
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
      int randIndex = rand() % 3;
      markers.push_back(vals[randIndex]);
    }
    geno.push_back(markers);
    markers.clear();
  }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // Timing Calculation
  using timepoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>;
  auto print_exec_time = [](timepoint start, timepoint stop) {
    auto duration_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    auto duration_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);
    auto duration_s = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(stop - start);

    std::cout << duration_s.count() << " s\n";
  };




  // Create the data
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  int numMarkers = 100;
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> old_genotypes;
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> new_genotypes;
  make_genotype_data(50, numMarkers, old_genotypes);
  make_genotype_data(6000, numMarkers, new_genotypes);

  auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << "*****************" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Total time for creating data" << std::endl;
  print_exec_time(start, stop);
  std::cout << "*****************" << std::endl;

  int nCols = old_genotypes[0].size();
  float threshold = 0.8;




  // Compare old_genotypes with new_genotypes
  start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  for (int i = 0; i < old_genotypes.size()-1; i++) {
    auto og = old_genotypes[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < new_genotypes.size()-1; j++) {
      auto ng = new_genotypes[j];
      int numComparisons = 0;
      int numMatches = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i < nCols; i++) {
        if (ng[i] != "--" && og[i] != "--") {
          if (ng[i] == og[i]) {
            numMatches++;
          }
          numComparisons++;
        }
      }
      float similarity = (float) numMatches / numComparisons;
      if (similarity >= threshold) {
        std::cout << i << " from old_genotypes and " << j << " from new_genotypes have high similarity: " << similarity << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }

  stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << "*****************" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Total time for comparison" << std::endl;
  print_exec_time(start, stop);
  std::cout << "*****************" << std::endl;
}
```

On 6,000 vs 5,000 it takes about 4 minutes. So for 6,000 vs 1.3M, it'll take about 17 hours.
It's quite slow. And I have no idea what I can do to improve the speed of the nested for loop. I'm a bit new to C++, so I don't know too many of the intricacies, but I can follow along with the jargon.

I'd really appreciate some pointers (pun intended :D) to help me optimize this. I am willing to try parallelization by breaking one of the datasets up into chunks and feeding each chunk to a core to compare against the second dataset (though don't know how to parallelize in C++). But I only want to explore parallelization after taking the serialized version as far as it can go (it'll help with the parallelized version anyway).

Comment: since there are only 3 values to compare it seems that converting them to a number and comparing vectors of `unsigned char` would be worth a shot

Comment: Hmmm, I'll try that out. Are char comparisons faster or int comparisons?

Comment: probably the same, whats really going to be hitting you is cache misses, you are jumping all over the place using vectors. You would be much better off if you could cram all the data into a tighter space (hence char) and access as sequentially as possible

Comment: Before you get into hand-optimizing, quick check: How are you compiling this code? Did you remember to turn on compiler optimizations? Simple `.size()` bounded loops often operate *much* more slowly with optimizations off (the compiler often makes the method call for each conditional test, and doesn't inline the indexing code). Even minimal optimization dramatically improves performance.

Comment: @pm100 Oh. from what I understand, vectors are contiguous memory blocks too, just like arrays. It's pivotal to their efficiency that the memory is continuous because it's the only way to allow fast access. So I'm unsure what you mean when you say that I'm jumping all over the place with vectors.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I had no idea 'compiler optimization' was a thing lol. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I'm just compiling with a simple `g++` command in my terminal. I don't think that's compiler optimizing, is it? So if I'm understanding correctly, maybe I can just store the `.size()` value in a variable and use that variable in the `for` loops. That way, even in unoptimized settings, it won't make repeated calls to the `.size()`. Is that right?

Comment: @ManyQuestions: They're contiguous, but the actual data is stored in heap allocated memory. For small vectors, the cost to follow a pointer to (and possibly page-in/pull into cache) the data will be a larger proportion of the work. That said, in this case, the savings isn't from avoiding `vector`, it's from avoiding `std::string`; even with the SSO making the `string` access local, it's faintly silly to have millions of `std::string` objects when simply encoding the three possible values as an `unsigned char` would dramatically reduce memory required (from 16-32 bytes/value to 1 byte/value).

Comment: @ManyQuestions: There's a *lot* of stuff that will add a *lot* of overhead if you don't optimize. Don't try to do it yourself for the simple stuff. As a rule, if you're checking performance, you want to be using *at least* `-O1` (to turn on the basic optimizations that avoid the stupidly easy to avoid overhead, without wildly reconfiguring your code), and typically `-O2`, `-Os` or `-O3` (to turn on more aggressive optimizations). Add `-flto` if you're building multiple files and want the compiler to be able to do cross-code unit optimizations (inlining functions from fileA into code in fileB).

Comment: vectors are contiguous but you have tons of tiny ones that will be spread out all over the place

Comment: Wow you guys weren't kidding there. Changing to data type from `string` to `unsigned char` took what was 4 minutes before, down to half a minute. And I still haven't done compiler optimization yet.!

Answer (score 0):

Comparing every element of the first list to every element of the second list does n^2 comparisons.  You can get much faster (except on degenerate lists) by instead sorting the two lists (which should take n log n comparisons for each list), then walk a pair of counters down the lists comparing what is at the two counters -- if equal, you found a match, increment counters to the first different element in each list and record the set of matches you just found; if element from list 1 is less than element from list 2, then increment counter 1 (because they are sorted, this element of list one must be ; if element from list 1 is greater than the element from list 2, increment counter 2; as soon as one counter goes beyond the end of its list you are done.  This does one compare and increments one counter each time, but can increment counters at most n times before it must hit the end of the lists, so is linear time except for the "record the set of matches you just found", which could be a large set if this is a degenerate pair of lists where most of both lists are the same.  But even in that worst possible case, it's only failing back to the same n^2 behavior of your current algorithm.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I don't think sorting will help here since I still need to compare every vector in one list to ever vector in the other list. And I'm not checking for equality, but for similarity above a threshold. And any pair that has similarity above a threshold, I need to record the pair. Though it could be that I'm not understanding your answer properly.